# How to dispaly data in table for form field in Admin edit form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

In my custom module I am saving data from front and it will display in the admin something like inquiry.

In admin side edit form I have to display some products data in table.

For example customer fill Name, Email, Message and multiple products Id.

so in Admin when we edit record from grid it will be like

```
Name: Test
Email : test@gmail.com
Message: Message
Product Data : 
    <table>
        <tr><th>Product ID</th><th>Product Name</th></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>Product 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>Product 2</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: do you want to show html data in grid ? or in admin edit form ?

Comment: What is the structure of the table for this enquiry form?

Comment: @Magecode Please check my ans, its working fine for me : https://prnt.sc/m40xuo, so it should be work for you as wll

Answer (score 1):

You can add your table HTML into "after_element_html" like following.

```
$fieldset->addField('some_id', 'text', [
     'name' => 'some_name',
     'label' => __('Some Label Here'),
     'readonly' => true,
     'after_element_html' => '<table>
                                <tr><th>Product ID</th><th>Product Name</th></tr>
                                <tr><td>1</td><td>Product 1</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>2</td><td>Product 2</td></tr>
                              </table>'
     ]);
```

Comment: @Magecode does this working for you ?